# DB2 LUW table locked while reading

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a range partitioned table in my database, it is range partitioned by a date column: transaction_date, with 1 partition per 1 month.

Now my problem is:
When running SQL statement to read data from the table,

```
select col1,col2 from mytable where ID=1
```

My table is very large so it takes a long time for the SQL to finish.
However, there is another ETL job to insert (append) data to the table at the same time, the insert operation cannot start until the read SQL finishes.

Any suggestions I can avoid this issue while reading data? Also are there any IBM official documents regarding this problem?

** EDIT 1:

```
$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and Db2 code release "SQL11011" with level
identifier "0202010F".

Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.1.1", "s1610100100", 
"DYN1610100100AMD64", and Fix Pack "1".

Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/v11.1". 

$ db2set -all
[i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
[i] DB2AUTOSTART=TRUE
[i] DB2OPTIONS=+c
[g] DB2FCMCOMM=TCPIP4
[g] DB2SYSTEM=<server hostname>
[g] DB2INSTDEF=db2inst1
```

** EDIT 2:

For the select and load SQL statement, I am not specifying any isolation level.

For the ETL job, it is an IBM DataStage job, the ETL insert is a bulk load append operation to insert data to a pre-existing range.

Comment: EDIT Your question to add new facts. (1) What is the isolation level of your SQL statement? Have you considered using 'uncommitted read' isolation level for your query (append `WITH UR` to the query, does it make any difference?   (2) what is the text output of the `db2set -all` for your Db2-instance on the server, and (3) what is the text output of the `db2level` command for the Db2-instance?

Comment: Can you also indicate whether the ETL insert is to a new partition, or to pre-existing ranges?  Is the ETL doing LOAD or logged-inserts (via import or ingest)? If the ETL job takes Z lock on the table ranges then you may be forced to schedule the jobs at different times.

Comment: @mao Hi, i have edited the question to include the information, to append ```WITH UR``` to the query, do you mean ```select col1,col2 from mytable where ID=1 WITH UR``` ? Or add it to the load SQL statement?

Comment: Append to query means: `select col1,col2 from mytable where ID=1 WITH UR`.  Ensure that the ID column is the first column in at least one index. Ensure that runstats are up to date, sampled, with distribution. Ask your DBA to monitor the locks taken by the DataStage job, and if it takes Z locks then you will need to schedule the jobs independently.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [MON_LOCKWAITS administrative view](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056601.html) to check what's happening during such a lock situation. You may optionally format a lock  with the `MON_FORMAT_LOCK_NAME` function to get more details on this as well.

```
SELECT 
  W.*
--, F.NAME, F.VALUE
FROM SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS W
--, TABLE(MON_FORMAT_LOCK_NAME(W.LOCK_NAME)) F
--WHERE W.REQ_APPLICATION_HANDLE = XXX -- if you know the holder's handle to reduce the amount of data returned
ORDER BY W.LOCK_NAME
;
```